# Problem with running auditpol command in gloang application

Tags: powershell, go, audit-logging

I need to be able to get audit policies for windows as part of golang application. I have prepared sample powershell auditpol command:
`auditpol /get /subcategory:'{0cce9215-69ae-11d9-bed3-505054503030}'`
and after running it using command line I get back adequate response:

```
System audit policy
Category/Subcategory                      Setting
Logowanie/wylogowywanie
  Logowanie                               Success and Failure
```

I'm using guid, because I need it to be langage independant.

Here's a golang code I'm using to execute command above:

```
args := []string{"/get", "/subcategory:'{0cce9215-69ae-11d9-bed3-505054503030}'"}
auditpolCmd := exec.Command("auditpol", args...)
out, err := auditpolCmd.Output()
```

And I'm getting following error:

```
Error 0x00000057 occurred:

The parameter is incorrect.
```

I tried tweaking the args - to put subcategory and guid in separate strings, using single and double quotes for guid, with and without colon after subcategory etc. Every time I'm getting the same error.

Is there a specific way to use parameters in args or maybe I'm missing something here?

In case it matters - I'm using go in version 1.19 on Windows 11 pro system.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `auditpol`, but most programs would not expect quotes in an argument like that.

Comment: Remove the single-quotes around the GUID: `args := []string{"/get", "/subcategory:{0cce9215-69ae-11d9-bed3-505054503030}"}`